# Split all the different graphs included in a n-quads file

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdflib, n-quads

I have a big n-quads file with a lot of statements included in a big number of different graphs
The lines of the file are as follow :

```
<http://voag.linkedmodel.org/voag#useGuidelines> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property> <http://voag.linkedmodel.org/schema/voag> .
```

The fourth element correspond to the graph's URI.

I would like to parse this file and split all the different graphs in new files or datastructures, one object per graph, preferably with RDFlib. I really don't know how to tackle this problem, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd just go with Linux command utilities like awk, grep, etc. - but if you really want to use rdflib, where exactly is the problem? The docs are online, loading graph and processing graphs is explained there very well. Just use a `ConjunctiveGraph` in which you load the file, and you're basically done or can just do whatever you want with each graph based on the N-Quads file

Comment: Well I loaded my file in a ConjuctiveGraph but I don't see how to split the different graphs afterwards, the documentation of rdflib is not very explicit

Comment: Nah, I do not agree with your statement: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.graph.ConjunctiveGraph - you can see the method `contexts()` which returns all contexts aka named graphs and with the `triples()` method you have access to all triples of a given context

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are such that all the graph URI's are together in a sequence then you can use [itertools' `groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to parse each one in turn:

```py
from itertools import groupby
import rdflib
def parse_nquads(lines):
    for group, quad_lines in groupby(lines, get_quad_label):
        graph = rdflib.Graph(identifier=group)
        graph.parse(data=''.join(quad_lines), format='nquads')
        yield graph
```

If the fourth element is always present and a URI (which is not guaranteed in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/n-quads/)) you can find it by searching for whitespace.

```py
import re
RDF_QUAD_LABEL_RE = re.compile("[ \t]+<([^>]*)>[ \t].\n$")
def get_quad_label(line):
    return RDF_QUAD_LABEL_RE.search(line).group(1)
```

Then you can process each graph from the input file into a new file or dataset

```py
with open('myfile.nquads', 'rt') as f:
  for graph in parse_nquads(f):
    ...
```